# dell xps 13, is it possible to swap ctrl and fn keys in bios?

Tags: keyboard, swap, dell-xps

This question was marked as a duplicate to a question about how to remap keys in the OS. This is not related to my question.

Although most keys can easily be remapped in this way the fn key is sometimes more complicated to remap, which is why some laptop manufacturers make it possible to swap the fn and left control key in the bios. An example of how to do this is for thinkpads can be found [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/How-can-I-swap-the-Fn-and-Ctrl-keys/td-p/656961) an explanation of how to do this on an older Dell xps model is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88063/how-to-invert-fn-keys-on-dell-laptop). My question is on wether this specific model has an option to do this, not about how to remap keys in general.

I'd like to know if it's possible to swap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys in BIOS on the dell project developer edition and/or xps machines.

I'm first and foremost interested in buying the 2015 model, but if this is possible with similar models (developer edition or xps) that will obviously give an indication of whether it's likely to be possible with the 2015 xps model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only use F4 or F5 as light change, the BIOS alows you to change that.

My function keys are multimedia keys (bright, play, vol up and down, wi-fi etc).

That's all. You can't remap the keys... just swap it's function!

Hope I was helpful

Info: I have a Dell XPS 13 9333.

Comment: Not sure how this is an answer to the question, I keep holding FN where I expect CTRL to be on the keyboard, this answer gives no details in how to make the FN believe it is  LEFT CTRL and the LEFT CTRL believe it is FN.